# Convert HTML Sidebar into JS Sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, twitter-bootstrap

HTML

```
<nav id="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-header">
          <img src="Files/Logo.png" width="150px" height="150px">
          <h3>Name</h3>
  </div>

  <ul class="list-unstyled components">
      <p>Dummy Heading</p>

      <li class="active">
         <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
         <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
           <li>
              <a href="#">Home 1</a>
           </li>
           <li>
              <a href="#">Home 2</a>
           </li>
           <li>
              <a href="#">Home 3</a>
           </li>
          </ul>
      </li>

  </ul>

</nav>
```

JS File

```
var myArray = [
  ["Site1.php", 0],
  ["Site2.php", 0],
  ["Site3.php", 0],
  ["Site4.php", 0],
  ["Site5.php", 0],
}

document.write(

'<button onclick="myAccFunc(1)"> Heading </button> '+

 ' <a href="'+myArray[0][0]+'" class="'+myArray[0][1]+'" > Website 1 </a> '+
 ' <a href="'+myArray[1][0]+'" class="'+myArray[1][1]+'" > Website 2 </a> '+
 ' <a href="'+myArray[2][0]+'" class="'+myArray[2][1]+'" > Website 3 </a> '+
 ' <a href="'+myArray[3][0]+'" class="'+myArray[3][1]+'" > Website 4 </a> '+
 ' <a href="'+myArray[4][0]+'" class="'+myArray[4][1]+'" > Website 5 </a> '+
'</div>'
```

);

The JS File was my SideBar menu and i had to move some code around to make the Site Mobile Friendly. Now my present code is the HTML Code. How do i create a JS File for that Nav Menu just like the one i had before because i can't put Sidenav code in HTML because i have a lot of menus? 
I just want to remove nav code from HTML and put it in a JS File with an array of sites and include that JS File in my HTML Page

EDIT

```
<nav id="sidebar">
  <script src="NAV.js">
      createSidebar(document.getElementById("sidebar"))
  </script>
</nav>
```

NAV

```
var myArray = [

  ["Site1.php", 0],
  ["Site2.php", 0],
  ["Site3.php", 0],
  ["Site4.php", 0],
  ["Site5.php", 0],
];


function createSidebar(/* DOMElement */ container) {
  var nav = document.createElement("nav");
  nav.setAttribute("id", "sidebar");
  nav.append(createSidebarHeader(), /* <div class="sidebar-header">... 
</div> */
createSidebarMenu()); /* <ul>...</ul> */
container.append(nav);
}

function createSidebarMenu() {
  var list = document.createElement("ul");
  list.setAttribute("class", "collapse list-unstyled");
  list.setAttribute("id", "homeSubmenu");
  for (var link of navlinks) {
    var li = list.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
    var a = li.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
    a.setAttribute("href", "#");
    a.append(link);
  }
  return list;
}
```

Comment: Are you using `w3.css`? I could recognise those "w3-"  css classes anywhere.

Comment: I used to use that. Now i dont. Please help me put the nav into a JS file and Include it in my Page @LearnforFun

Comment: is the updated question better? @LearnforFun

Comment: It is easier to understand now, and is that div meant to be unopened in the JS file?

Comment: More importantly, Am i right in saying that: you want to put all the links in the JS file and render it in HTML from there.

Comment: Yes i want to put the links in JS like i had done before and just include the file @LearnforFun

Comment: You have created a `<script>` element that has both `src` attribute and content - this will not work: only the `src` will be used and the content will be ignored.

Comment: So what should i do instead of this? @Guss

Comment: Use one `<script>` tag to load the external Javascript file, and another (without `src` attribute) to write the local script to call `createSidebar()`

Answer (score 0):

Your old Javascript file has 1 serious problem - you are using `document.write()` which is a big no-no in current web practice: it must be run before the document is ready - otherwise, it will overwrite all the other content - and even if used right it causes a major slowdown as the browser has to reinterpret the entire document multiple times.

You probably want to convert your old Javascript code and the new HTML code to DOM editing using the DOM API.

It might looks something like this (this is not a full example, I'm making a **very** simplified sidebar):

```
var navlinks = [
  ["Site1.php", 0],
  ["Site2.php", 0],
  ["Site3.php", 0],
  ["Site4.php", 0],
  ["Site5.php", 0],
];

function createSidebar(/* DOMElement */ container) {
  var nav = document.createElement("nav");
  nav.setAttribute("id", "sidebar");
  nav.append(createSidebarHeader(), /* <div class="sidebar-header">...</div> */
             createSidebarMenu()); /* <ul>...</ul> */
  container.append(nav);
}

function createSidebarMenu() {
  var list = document.createElement("ul");
  list.setAttribute("class", "collapse list-unstyled");
  list.setAttribute("id", "homeSubmenu");
  for (var link of navlinks) {
    var li = list.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
    var a = li.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
    a.setAttribute("href", "#");
    a.append(link);
  }
  return list;
}
```

Then from your main document, after loading the Javascript file, you can have a "container" for your sidebar (let's say - a `<div id="sidebar-holder">`) and call `createSidebar(document.getElementById("sidebar-holder"))`.

There are various Javascript frameworks that will help with the tedious job of creating HTML elements using the DOM API - Google for them or sth.

Comment: i followed your answer but the Side bar is not showing. When i replace the <script src="NAV.js"> with my old bar it works

Comment: Did you call `createSidebar()` from your code, with an appropriate container element? Do you get any Javascript errors in the debug console when you run that code?

Comment: Look to the edited question. i did call but nothing. no error too. i even placed an alert inside the function and the function is not even getting called